# Ideal test duration for Performance Test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have 5 Scenarios in total, and 70 Users segregated to different Scenarios which runs for around 15 Minutes only with 1 Loop configuration.

Is it ideal test duration to evaluate the realistic Performance results?

Or do I need to adjust with the test duration?

Any suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. 70 concurrent users doesn't look like a real "load" to me, moreover given you have only one loop you may run into the situation when some users have already finished executing their scenarios and were shut down and some are still running or even have not yet been started. So I would recommend monitoring the real concurrency using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener to see how many users were online at the given stage of the test.

Normally the following testing types are conducted:

- [Load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) - putting the system under **anticipated** load and ensuring that main metrics (i.e. response time and throughput) are matching [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)s or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)s
- [Soak testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) - basically the same as load testing, but it assumes prolonged duration (several hours, overnight or over the weekend). This testing type allows to discover obvious and non-obvious [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
- [Stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) - starting with anticipated number of users and gradually increasing the load until response time starts exceeding acceptable threshold or errors start occurring (whatever comes the first). If will shed some light on the slowest or most fragile component, to wit the first [performance bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)

Check out [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough/) article for more information on the aforementioned performance testing types.

No matter which test you're conducting consider increasing (and decreasing) the load gradually, i.e. come up with proper [ramp-up](https://www.webperformance.com/load-testing-tools/blog/2009/05/estimating-load-test-ramp-up-times/) (and ramp-down) strategies, this way you will be able to correlate increasing load with i.e. increasing response time

Comment: I use the 'Active Threads Over Time' Listener, all 70 concurrent users runs for around 5 minutes simultaneously out of total 15 minutes test run. 

Can I increase the Loop Count to 2, so that it lasts for around 30 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

Performance Tests in java is a bit tricky, it can vary wildly depending on what other programs are running on the system and what its load is.

In an ideal world, you need to use a dedicated system, if you can't make sure to quit all programs you're running (including the IDE), The Java HotSpot compiler kicks in when it sees a ‘hot spot’ in your code. It is therefore quite common that your code will run faster over time! So, you should adapt and repeat your testing methods, investigate memory and CPU usage.

or even better you can use a profiler. There are plenty around, both free profilers and demos / time-locked trials of commercials strength ones.